# Conga Query get all contacts from Opportunity record

Tags: administration, related-list, conga

Using soql how can I get all the contacts from account via Opportunity object ? I have my button on Opportunity do i need subqueries for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id =: opp.AccountId
```

you can add other fields on the query if you want.

Hope that is helpful

Comment: hi @dibocor I paste your code on Conga Query 'Soql Statement' and gives me malformed query

Comment: SELECT Name, ID,
(SELECT NAME, Amount FROM Opportunities WHERE ID = '{pv0}'),
(SELECT Id, LastName,Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account

it gives me all the account w/ contacts hmm